# I don't want the command block to "scan" me

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need a command block to scan people on a certain range, but I don't want the command block to detect me is that possible?

I'm using this command:

```
/gamemode 2 @p[r=2]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind I just found the answer by myself, just needed to put "name=!pseudo".

So it gave that:

```
/gamemode adventure @p[name=!yourpseudo,r=2]
```

The fonction "name=" is here to include to the research the pseudo of someone, the "!" is here to say "exept that one" so the command here will work like that :

- First it'll search the nearest player.
- Then it'll check if his name is not biscuit for example.
- And third it'll check if he is in a range of 2.
- And fourth if all the conditions are met he'll be set on gamemode 2.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what that pseudo does? While it's really nice that you found the answer yourself, others may have the same question later and would be able to find it here.

Comment: I've edited it !